# Failure in running Faster R-CNN repo

Tags: mac, installation, repository, cuda

I have a MacBook Pro 16in with the following GPU: AMD Radeon Pro 5300M.

I have been trying to run the demo in the Faster R-CNN repo [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark) but I am not being able to run the demo.

I think it might be due to not being able to install CUDA, since my GPU is AMD and not NVIDIA. The installation requirements are available [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark/blob/master/INSTALL.md).

Has anyone been able to run it?

Comment: If the system requires CUDA, then it requires both the hardware and software that comprises this system. Unless you can identify the specific components that require CUDA and rewrite these to not require it you won't be able to run this.

Answer (score 0):

If the application requires CUDA then you'll need CUDA to run it.

You have three choices:

1. Get CUDA hardware
2. Find a similar product that doesn't require CUDA
3. Identify the code that requires CUDA in this product and rewrite it not to